# tPostgresqlInput - How to convert input to Null-if-empty?

Tags: talend, informatica

I want to trim each column value to null if they are empty.

Is there a way to attach an inbuilt talend function to those column values? I think informatica has something like that.

PS: I need to do that in talend, not in sql level.

[image]

The rows goes to another table in another db:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like to solve this with Java, I'm sure there are other more graphical ways to do this.
If we put a tJavaRow inbetween, then press generate code it would result in:

```
output_row.plateid = input_row.plateid;
```

If we change this to:

```
output_row.plateid = (input_row.plateid == null || input_row.plateid.length() == 0) ? null : input_row.plateid ;
```

Then we get the desired results. **null** stays **null**, **empty string** also becomes **null**.

Answer (score 0):

In most t***Input components you have trim all columns option. Look for it in advanced settings.
[image]